# Determine rate law from experimental data

Tags: experimental-chemistry, kinetics

For the reaction A -> B + C we have the following experimental data.

\begin{array}{cccc}
\text{Experiment} & \ce{P_A} &\ce{P_B} &\ce{P_C} & \text{Reaction rate}\ce{}\\\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3.5\\
2 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1.1\\
3 & 10 & 1 & 1& 0.7\\
4 & 2 & 5 & 1& 1.9\\
5 & 2 & 10 & 1& 1.6\\
6 & 3 & 0 & 5& 1.5\\
7 & 3 & 0 & 10& 1.2\\
8 & 0 & 5 & 8& 0\\
9 & 3 & 3 & 3& 1.4\\
\hline
\end{array}

I have been searching around the internet, but it seems like many of the examples that I found include fewer experiments and/or different chemical reactions.
I am thus wondering what method one can use to find the appropiate rate law, and if one uses all of the experimental data? Looking at all the data at once it is harder to see the pattern.

Supposedly this should be possible to do without using regression with Excel or other computer software.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: There are no good answers here for an arbitrarily complicated system. Usually, some sort of curve fitting for each variable with possibly brutal application of Okkam's razor. Here, though, it's not even clear your data make sense. Why is the reaction rate inversely proportional to the reactant? Something isn't right.

Comment: That is a good observation. Maybe the whole point is that the data doesn't make sense or that some of the data should be disregarded (maybe due to human errors ).